# Protecting 12 VDC against 220 V

Tags: mains, over-voltage-protection

I've made the power circuit for my project with some protections.
(Fuse, Reverse Polarity, Undervoltage, working Vin is 12~24).
The circuit is supplied by user. Any voltage between 0~30 is acceptable and managed in power section of circuit.

The last problem I have is if the user (mistakenly or deliberately) plugs the supply to mains line (220 V). that's 220 V instead of expected 12-30 V Vin.

**How to protect against Vin > 30v? (which most probably only occurs in case of Vin = 220 V)**.

Thoughts and info:

- Varistors are not suitable here as they're slow.
- Not sure if any fuse is fast enough to protect sensitive chips from microseconds of high voltage.
- Can't find mosfets with high enough VbrDSS (Drain Source BreakDown) for high-side-switching.
- Startup delay up to 5sec is acceptable if your solution requires it.
- Using relays and/or optocouplers or any other switching method is acceptable.
- Please don't mention labeling the device power jack, or anything that relies on user.

Thanks.

Comment: How much current flows at 24 V? How much voltage drop is acceptable? The usual solution is a series fuse, resistor, and a parallel clamp of zener diodes.

Comment: Can you make your project need 220 V AC to power it? That way, no harm will come if they plug it into 220 V AC or 30 V DC.

Comment: @tomnexus max current is ~1A (0.95A). max accepted voltage drop is 2v (if Vin=12v)

Comment: What does "*The circuit is supplied by user*" mean? The user wires it up? The user is allowed to put a mains plug on it? You could sell more devices if you let the user blow it up.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thought about it too. that makes considerable amounts of heat in the circuit that I can't deal with.

Comment: @Transistor it's a device which the supply voltage is provided by the end user. (hopefully the recommended 12vDC is supplied. but I have to protect against 220vAC OV situation since no adapter will be included with the device.)

Comment: This is usually done with the physical interface. For example, you don't ever use a figure 8 inlet for 12V, because that plug is usually associated with 110V or 220V. OTOH, if you use a barrel jack in your design, and somebody sends 220V over it, that's their fault. Defensive design is all well and good, but if you overdo it, at some point it becomes paranoia and detrimental to your design.

Comment: That things usually done with using different type of connectors, making impossible to mess with input source.

Comment: @Elementronics A [Mean Well IRM-15-12](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2547886.pdf) has an efficiency of 82%, so it would only be dissipating about 2.6 W at 1 A output. Similar modules are available from other suppliers if you can't source that one.